# Why is fill(0) creating entries and breaking the group?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

On a project where we use influx 1.7 we have a query that behaves strangely. Basically what we're trying to do is

- average the data to align the time periods
- take the max out of these time periods
- sum these max values

Here is an example that reproduces the behavior.

Insert some example data

```
> INSERT test,source=source1 value=10 1643202000000000000
> INSERT test,source=source1 value=30 1643203800000000000
> INSERT test,source=source2 value=20 1643202000000000000
> INSERT test,source=source2 value=60 1643203800000000000
> INSERT test,source=source2 value=20 1643202900000000000
> INSERT test,source=source2 value=50 1643204700000000000
```

Change precision for readability and check the data

```
> precision rfc3339
> select * from test
name: test
time                 source  value
----                 ------  -----
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z source1 10
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z source2 20
2022-01-26T13:15:00Z source2 20
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z source1 30
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z source2 60
2022-01-26T13:45:00Z source2 50
```

Based on what I described, I would expect the final sum to equal max(10, mean(20,20)) + max(30, mean(60,50) = max(10,20) + max(30,55) = 20 + 55 = 75

If we select the mean value using fill(0) and fill(none) that's when things start to get weird, some values are added for no apparent reason

```
> select mean(value) from test group by time(30m), source fill(0)
name: test
tags: source=source1
time                 mean
----                 ----
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 10
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 30
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0

name: test
tags: source=source2
time                 mean
----                 ----
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 20
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 55
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0
> select mean(value) from test group by time(30m), source fill(none)
name: test
tags: source=source1
time                 mean
----                 ----
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 10
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 30

name: test
tags: source=source2
time                 mean
----                 ----
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 20
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 55
```

But things start to get crazy when we try to select the max value for each time period

```
> select max(value) from (select mean(value) as value from test group by time(30m), source fill(0)) group by time(30m)
name: test
time                 max
----                 ---
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 10
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 20
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 30
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 55
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 0
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 0
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z 0
> select max(value) from (select mean(value) as value from test group by time(30m), source fill(none)) group by time(30m)
name: test
time                 max
----                 ---
2022-01-26T13:00:00Z 20
2022-01-26T13:30:00Z 55
2022-01-26T14:00:00Z 
2022-01-26T14:30:00Z 
2022-01-26T15:00:00Z
```

Of course the final result differs

```
> select sum(value) from (select max(value) as value from (select mean(value) as value from test group by time(30m), source fill(0)) group by time(30m))
name: test
time                 sum
----                 ---
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 115
> select sum(value) from (select max(value) as value from (select mean(value) as value from test group by time(30m), source fill(none)) group by time(30m))
name: test
time                 sum
----                 ---
1970-01-01T00:00:00Z 75
```

The query with fill(0) seems to have broken the group as all values are getting selected.

Am fill(0) broken or am I missing/misusing something ? Could anyone justify this behavior ?